# How can i tell if an Exception was deliberately thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I would like to catch an exception an tell if it was me that deliberately threw the error or something else like a runtime error (object not instance of an object).

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("throw this", "these can be many possible values");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    if (IThrew) // <--- how can i tell if i threw or not?
    {
        exReport = "one thing"; // <--- Should go in here in this example.
    }
    else
    {
        exReport = "another thing";
    }

    throw new FaultException<ExceptionReport>(exReport, new FaultReason(ex.Message), new FaultCode("Receiver"));

}
```

---

**Clarification:**

I need keep record of all the exceptions then at the end display them in an exceptions report (array of exceptions). This is part of a [schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd) I am REQUIRED to follow. (so please don't ask me to do it another way).

I have it all working great it outputs something like:

```xml
...
<soap:Detail>
<ows:ExceptionReport>
 <Exception exceptionCode="…" locator="…">
  <ExceptionText>…</ExceptionText>
 </Exception>
 <Exception exceptionCode="…" locator="…">
  <ExceptionText>…</ExceptionText>
 </Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
</soap:Detail>
...
```

The problem is that when i'll have a few errors already in my ExceptionReport, then a runtime error will occur.

But i've realized i'm going the wrong way about this... as Gary mentioned... i shouldn't be using exceptions as flow control.

Comment: An exception is **always** deliberately thrown by some part of the system. Please clarify what you are looking for (and why). Are you looking for a distinction of checked vs. unchecked exceptions as in Java?

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for flow control, so it's generally irrelevant whether the exception is thrown by user code or the run-time. Either way, it's an exceptional condition that you either need to know how to handle, or give up and let it fail.

Comment: @Cody: This isn't "using exception for flow control", it's converting exceptions so that the correct message will be returned to the user of a web service.

Comment: @Matti: My exception objects have a `Message` property that provides a description of the exception.

Comment: @Cody: So do a lot of built-in exceptions and you probably don't want to show all of those to the user, so you need to filter. Another possibility is that he wants to provide the same message to the user for all exceptions, but wants to log them differently or something (this would be better done in a global exception handler though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't tell *why* an exception was thrown.

What you **can** do is create your own exception classes so you can catch them - these will be the exceptions thrown on purpose. That is, since you created the exception class, the framework is not going to throw these.

```
try
{
 // something
}
catch(MyCustomException ex)
{
   // Thrown by Application logic
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
   // Could by thrown by anything
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a different exception.  Give it its own catch clause.

Answer (score 5):

Use a special type of exception for your own exceptions and check for that.

Otherwise you'd have to resort to inspecting stack traces to see if the origin is one of your assemblies, which is both ugly and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the call stack on the exception and see if the top of it is your code - if so you directly produced the exception but there is no way to tell if you used a `throw` or, say, divided an int by zero

as the others have said the only sure fire way is to throw exceptions that could not be thrown by anyone else - ones that you control and have a common distinct base class